# Compare two columns (Material and Size) and get output from another column(Quote Amount) in EXCEL

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two columns i.e. Size and Material. Based on the values of Size and Material, I want to get the Quote Amount on Result Column.

Below is the picture for the excel.

[image]

What I tried is: =VLOOKUP(E2,A2:C207,1,FALSE).

Anything wrong with my formula.

Please correct me

Comment: The link to table is https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aq7e7KPouB0Yi0QOn5cgIoAuv2W8

Comment: Need more information.. | column A-C is the data column. And Column E++ is the Result/Output column.. | In order to get the "Result".. the user must enter the "Size and Material".. my question is.. in which cell should the user enter these information ?